# Asp.Net Core No DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I have a custom `AuthorizationHandler` in my Asp.Net Core API project which authorizes requests based on Tokens been passed in the `Headers`.

The `Handler` works fine as in it invoked on runtime however am getting the following error

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no 
>   DefaultChallengeScheme found.

I have registered my settings in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenAuthorizationHandler>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

The default properties of the project is enable Anonymous Authentication and disable  Windows Authentication .

If  you want to choose **IIS default authentication** as your authenticationScheme  , you need to modify the project's properties to enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication :

- Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select **Properties**.
- Select the **Debug** tab.
- Clear the check box for **Enable Anonymous Authentication**.
- Select the check box for **Enable Windows Authentication**.
- Save and close the property page.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#iisiis-express

Or you could add others authenticationSchemes (cookie-based authentication , JWT bearer authentication etc) , refer to [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x) for more details .